# Seg fault with strcmp

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have a function that does a simple math calculation based on what operation we're reading in.

The "operation" char is read in off the command line, and should be a single character string.

I'm getting a seg fault though when I'm using the strcmp function.

Not sure why this is happening. Can someone help out? Code below:

```
int syscall(int param1, int param2, char operation, int* result) 
{ 
if (param2 == 0 && (strcmp(operation, "/") == 0))
    {
        return -1; 
    }
    else if (strcmp(operation, "+") == 0)
    {
        *result = param1 + param2;
        return 0; 
    }
    else if (strcmp(operation, "-") == 0)
    {
        *result = param1 - param2; 
        return 0; 
    }
    else if (strcmp(operation, "*") == 0)
    {
        *result = param1 * param2; 
        return 0; 
    }
    else if (strcmp(operation, "/") == 0)
    {
        *result = param1 / param2; 
        return 0; 
    }
    else 
    {
        return -1; 
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't the full example, so there's no way to know how the segmentation fault is happening...

Comment: @DustinNieffenegger You don't need everything. Assume the values are getting into the function as expected (two ints, a char, and a pointer to an int).

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem, after reading the link. You don't know where the problem is in your code, or you would not be asking the question. You could get your first badge by reading the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: `strcmp` takes a pointer to characters, and you're giving it a char. It will try to dereference your char as a pointer, leading to a seg fault.

Comment: "Not sure why this is happening. "... "You don't need everything. Assume..."  real debugging is not done via guesses and assumptions.   Don't come here asking for help and then tell us you won't bother to provide a complete reproduction of the problem.   Boo.

Answer (score 3):

strcmp trying find size of your string and char dont have any null terminator because its not string.
actually you dont even give address of variable to strcmp. you just give value as address then strcmp trying read some address between 0 - 255.

you can just use:

```
int syscall(int param1, int param2, char operation, int* result) 
{ 
    if (param2 == 0 && operation == '/')
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (operation == '+')
    {
        *result = param1 + param2;
        return 0; 
    }
    else if (operation == '-')
    {
        *result = param1 - param2; 
        return 0; 
    }
    else if (operation == '*')
    {
        *result = param1 * param2;
        return 0;
    }
    else if (operation == '/')
    {
        *result = param1 / param2;
        return 0;
    }
    else 
    {
        return -1; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A char is not the same as a single character string. strcmp expects a character string.

Supplying a string in the parameters should help.

```
int syscall(int param1, int param2, char operation[], int* result)
  { /* rest of code */
```

But if you are only comparing chars, just compare chars and forget about strcmp().